# Can't find or open PDB - VS 2013 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files

I tried to execute my program and a bunch of can't find PDB appeared in the output. 
So i went to:
Tools / Options / Debugging / Symbols and I checked Microsoft Symbol Server. It solved a lot of the PDB issues, but one still remains.

> 'Lab3Serveur_A2012.exe' (Win32) : Chargé 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.

I dont know what to do... i went to see if the file WLIDNSP.DLL was in the folder and it was... any ideas?

Comment: I think it's saying it cannot find a PDB that corresponds to that DLL: Microsoft might just not publish one.

Comment: But the project was working as is on another computer, how can i make it work on mine?

Comment: A missing PDB won't stop it working? You can try looking in the symbol cache (used to be in c:\windows\symbols, not sure if it still is) on the other machine to find the PDB and copy it over if it's no longer up for download, provided that is you have the exact same DLL binary on both machines.

Comment: This is entirely normal.  And no, you don't *really* want to debug an injected Windows Live DLL.  Focus on debugging **your** code.